# AWS SQS MessageAttribtues Purpose

Tags: python, boto3, amazon-sqs

I'm just wondering what the purpose of sending MessageAttributes with a message using SQS with Boto3. Is this to tell the receiver (if it were a python script receiving the message from the queue) to automatically cast the parts of the message as those relevant data types in the python interpreter? Like for instance, if sending a datetime string, and passing a MessageAttributes defining the type of data structure (along with the format of the datetime string), would boto3 automatically parse it and cast it as a datetime object? Or am I misunderstanding this.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing Python/Boto3 specific about Message Attributes. [SQS Message Attributes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-message-attributes.html) are just a way to include metadata on SQS messages. I'm not aware of any AWS SDK in any programming language that performs data conversions automatically based on SQS Message Attributes.

From the linked page:

> Amazon SQS lets you include structured metadata (such as timestamps,
>   geospatial data, signatures, and identifiers) with messages using
>   message attributes. Each message can have up to 10 attributes. Message
>   attributes are optional and separate from the message body (however,
>   they are sent alongside it). Your consumer can use message attributes
>   to handle a message in a particular way without having to process the
>   message body first.